# How to convert a string with commas into cells

Tags: excel, list, vba

I want to convert a simple string as follows into cells in a row:

"Apple, Pear, Grapes, Strawberry, Lemmon, Cherry"
I could write them by my own, but in case of bigger lists it can demmand quite some time.

How do I do it in Excel? Is there a tool other than Excel for the job.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use **Text to Columns** wizard on th *Data Tools* group on the Data Ribbon tab.

Comment: You should post it as an answer. This is the best solution in Excel. I will not post to avoid stealing your show :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is constant you should use **Text to Columns.**
If the data is the result of a formula, then with data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across.

Answer (score 2):

use Text to Columns wizard on the Data Tools group on the Data Ribbon tab. – 
[image]